# How do I go about writing this code?

Tags: c++, c

I have to write a program to output the following text (no more, no less):

```
   1 
  12
 123
1234
```

Being a beginner, I'm totally stuck. What is the best way to approach this? What algorithm should I use?

Comment: Tell us what you have done so far, then we will correct the source code... Dont expect sky without trying to reach it...

Comment: String tmp = ""; for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {System.out.println(tmp += i); }

Comment: What problem? You haven't described any problem.

Comment: @Romain: That doesn't even compile!

Comment: I never get it: why would someone take a programming course when he obviously don't like it ?!

Comment: It seems quite clear that user608062 wants someone to hand him or her some source code to produce the given output but is completely lacking in the social skills required to obtain such an answer.

Comment: @Romain Wrong language and wrong output (left justified rather than right justified).

Answer (score 6):

Here's some pseudo-code to get you started. I don't give real code for obvious learning/homework questions since it does you no good in the long term.

```
for i = 1 to 4:                  # four lines.
    for j = 1 to 4-i:            # each line starts with some spaces.
        output a space
    for j = 1 to i:              # followed by the digits.
        output j
    output new line              # move to next line.
```

*Your* job is to actually run that program in your head, writing down the contents of variables as you go and recording what gets output.

Then, once you fully understand how and why it works, convert it to your language of choice. Look, here's a sheet to get you stared:

```
  i      j    output
-----  -----  ------
  1
```

Comment: +1 You nailed it with getting it going in his head. That should get him going.